# android drawBitmap RBG_888

Tags: android, rgb, alpha, drawbitmap

I'd like to blit a 24bit bitmap.
Of course I can use the ARGB_8888 bitmap mode, but I don't care about the alpha channel.

My bitmap is a background.
So I'd like to inprove performance by indicate to android that there is no reason to use alpha channel.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: yes, but if it's possible I'd like to use RGB_888